# How to add faded edges to a rectangle drawable?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable

I currently have the following drawable which creates a rectangle with rounded edges, a semi-transparent black background and transparent edges (in case I want to show them later):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#50FFFFFF"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="5dip"
                android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

My question is how could I modify this so that the edges of the rectangle's background fade, to give a softer appearance?

Comment: Do you need just half-transparent background or some kind of animation that makes it?

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev I already have a half-transparent background with the colour's hex value beginning with opacity value `50`.  I just need the edges to be faded, so I guess you could say the edges would be partially transparent.  There doesn't need to be any kind of movement/animation shown for the faded edges.

Comment: use nine patch drawable

Comment: @Paradox it seems to be quite easy stuff - just replace `@android:color/transparent` with a corresponding color for your edges item (stroke).

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev I don't mean the edge lines specifically, but rather the edges of the entire image.  Something like this http://i38.tinypic.com/16ke144.jpg

Comment: then use nine patch drawable - android uses them almost everywhere

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this for work once.

Just make a layer-list with multiple rectangle each with increasing opacity and padding

code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#03101010" />
            <corners android:radius="24dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#06101010" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        android:top="8dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#09101010" />
            <corners android:radius="16dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="12dp"
        android:left="12dp"
        android:right="12dp"
        android:top="12dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#12101010" />
            <corners android:radius="12dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The number of layers may vary depending on the color of your primary rectangle and the background.